EF Core 8 CosmosDb "Nullable object must have a value" while getting entity with list of ValueObjects
I've been moving Infrastructure of my project to Ef Core 8 from CosmosClient and I've been getting exception `System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value", while getting entity that contains List of ValueObjects
My entity:
public sealed class Test : BaseEntity
{
    public string ShortName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public List<Marker> Markers { get; set; } = [];

    public Test(string name, string? shortName = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        ShortName = shortName ?? name;
        Id = ShortName.EncodePolishLetterAndWhiteChars();
    }

    public Test() { }
}

Marker:
public sealed class Marker : BaseEntity
{
    public Marker() { }
    public Marker(string name,
        decimal? lowerNorm = null,
        decimal? upperNorm = null,
        string? unit = null,
        string? shortName = null)
    {
        ShortName = shortName ?? name;
        Name = name;
        LowerNorm = lowerNorm;
        UpperNorm = upperNorm;
        Unit = unit;
    }

    public string ShortName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public decimal? LowerNorm { get; set; }
    public decimal? UpperNorm { get; set; }
    public string? Unit { get; set; }
}

DbContext OnModelCreating:
...
 modelBuilder
            .Entity<Test>()
            .ToContainer("Tests")
            .HasNoDiscriminator()
            .HasPartitionKey(r => r.ShortName);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
            .Property(r => r.Id)
            .ToJsonProperty("id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
            .ComplexProperty(r => r.Markers)
            .IsRequired();
...

I've tried making every property nullable, making List nullable and making List of nullable Markers. When I do not set Markers as Complex Property I get Test but List is empty.

Can you share the full exception/stack trace? That might point you at exactly what code is throwing it and/or for which property


System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value

The above error occurs when trying to use a nullable object's method or property without first checking its values. The code uses ComplexProperty method, it is intended for configuring non-collection properties, not collections. If EF Core interprets the Markers collection as nullable and tries to access its properties without proper initialization or checking for null, it results the error.
Try with the below code, it uses OwnsMany method to configure the ownership of a collection of Markers entities by the Test entity. It configures EF Core to handle the relationship between the Test entity and its collection of Markers value objects. This prevents the Nullable object must have a value error from occurring during the proper store and retrieval of data from Cosmos DB as shown in the below output.
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseCosmos(
            "<EndPointUri>",
            "<PrimaryKey>",
            databaseName: "firstDb"
        );
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
            .ToContainer("firstCont")
            .HasNoDiscriminator()
            .HasPartitionKey(r => r.ShortName);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
            .Property(r => r.Id)
            .ToJsonProperty("id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
            .OwnsMany(r => r.Markers);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var context = new AppDbContext();

        // Sample data insertion
        var test1 = new Test("Test Entity 1", "Test1")
        {
            Markers = new List<Marker>
            {
                new Marker("Marker One", 10, 20, "kg", "Marker1"),
                new Marker("Marker Two", 5, 15, "m", "Marker2")
            }
        };

        var test2 = new Test("Test Entity 2", "Test2")
        {
            Markers = new List<Marker>
            {
                new Marker("Marker Three", 8, 18, "lbs", "Marker3")
            }
        };

        context.Tests.Add(test1);
        context.Tests.Add(test2);

        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("Data inserted successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while saving data: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

Output:
Data inserted successfully.


Could you try with the above answer and let me know if any errors you are facing with.
